# SQL, using Group by until specific trend (increment, decrement, same)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I would like to know how can i modify my code for considering all the same values of suppose 10 as UP till the time it is incrementing and then down for decrement and SAME if there is no change till the time there is no variation in the value (increment, decrement, same).

Here is my code :

```
;with etape1 as
    (
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY mnth) AS id,* from [InsideTSQL2008].[alioune].[Sales]
    )
    ,
 etape2 as
 (
 select 
    a.id, b.mnth AS START , a.mnth AS FINISH , 
   a.qty - b.qty AS TREND
FROM
   etape1 a
   LEFT  JOIN etape1 b
   on a.id = b.id+1
   )
   select * from etape2;
```

My Result is :

```
id  START       FINISH      TREND
1   NULL        2007-12-01  NULL
2   2007-12-01  2008-01-01  10
3   2008-01-01  2008-02-01  10
4   2008-02-01  2008-03-01  10
5   2008-03-01  2008-04-01  10
6   2008-04-01  2008-05-01  0
7   2008-05-01  2008-06-01  -10
8   2008-06-01  2008-07-01  -10
9   2008-07-01  2008-08-01  -10
10  2008-08-01  2008-09-01  -10
11  2008-09-01  2008-10-01  10
12  2008-10-01  2008-11-01  -10
13  2008-11-01  2008-12-01  20
14  2008-12-01  2009-01-01  10
15  2009-01-01  2009-02-01  10
16  2009-02-01  2009-03-01  -40
```

My final result as required should be like :

```
Start        End      Trend

200712      200712     unknown
200801      200804     UP
200805      200805     SAME
200806      200809     DOWN
200810      200810     UP
200811      200811     DOWN
200812      200812     UP
200903      200903     DOWN
200904      200905     SAME
200906      200907     UP
```

Any help would be really helpful; Thanks

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved...)

Comment: If SQL Server, which version?  2012, and higher, has some useful functions for this kind of problem.

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2014

Comment: Can you tell me the functions I can use to solve this issue?

Comment: I think you should use SQL Cursor (Fetch) or SQL while loop (this has better performance than Cursor).

Although this is a solution, it will cause performance problems. So I believe that you should reduce this by finding alternative solutions.

Comment: For example, if you use this data in an application, I would recommend you to do this operations in your business layer. This will reduce the cost for SQL Server.     

If you have no application and if there is a high transaction on the database, you may think about taking a snapshot of it and working on it.     

I also would like to add a few tips: 
1- Please search about (nolock) keyword. Do you really need to lock these tables?
2- Do you really need to use * and select all the data? Maybe only necessary columns would be enough? (better performance)

Comment: The last three rows are not included in your expected result, and those most important. Are rows `13/14/15` combined into a single row 'UP' or `13 -> UP` and `14/15 -> UP` or `13 -> UP` and `14/15 -> DOWN`?

Comment: No, I have just given an example , how i wish to have my result...
200712         200712     unknown
200801  200804    UP
200805  200805    SAME
200806   200809     DOWN
200810  200810    UP
200811  200811    DOWN
200812  200812     UP
200903  200903    DOWN
200904  200905    SAME
200906  200907     UP

Comment: In SQL Server 2012+ you can use `LEAD` or `LAG` functions to look at the next/previous row for calculating your trend. It is much more efficient than joining the table to itself. It would help, if you edited the question and added your sample data together with the expected result **that matches** the sample data. Don't put a wall of numbers in the comments. Comments don't have formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me a few goes (and a few hours), but I think I have what you want:

```
DECLARE @Sales AS TABLE (mnth datetime, qty int)

INSERT INTO @Sales
SELECT '2016-01-01', 10 UNION ALL 
SELECT '2016-02-01', 20 UNION ALL 
SELECT '2016-03-01', 30 UNION ALL 
SELECT '2016-04-01', 40 UNION ALL 
SELECT '2016-05-01', 40 UNION ALL 
SELECT '2016-06-01', 30 UNION ALL 
SELECT '2016-07-01', 20 UNION ALL 
SELECT '2016-08-01', 30 UNION ALL 
SELECT '2016-09-01', 40 UNION ALL 
SELECT '2016-10-01', 45 UNION ALL 
SELECT '2016-11-01', 50

;WITH etape1 AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY mnth) AS id, * FROM @Sales
)
, etape2 AS (
    SELECT id, lag(mnth) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS START, mnth AS FINISH, CASE WHEN qty - LAG(qty) OVER (ORDER BY id) < 0 THEN -1 WHEN qty - LAG(qty) OVER (ORDER BY id) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TREND
    FROM etape1
)
, etape3 AS (
    SELECT id, START, FINISH, TREND, lag(TREND) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS PrevTrend
    FROM etape2
) 
, etape4 AS (
    SELECT id, START, FINISH, TREND, SUM(CASE WHEN TREND = PREVTREND THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS Change
    FROM etape3
)
SELECT MIN(START) AS START, MAX(FINISH) AS FINISH, CASE WHEN MIN(TREND) IS NULL THEN 'Unknown' WHEN MIN(TREND) < 0 THEN 'Down' WHEN MIN(TREND) > 0 THEN 'Up' WHEN MIN(Start) is NULL THEN 'Unknown' ELSE 'Same' END AS TREND
FROM etape4
GROUP BY Change
ORDER BY START
```

Results are:

```
START       FINISH      TREND
NULL        2016-01-01  Unknown
2016-01-01  2016-04-01  Up
2016-04-01  2016-05-01  Same
2016-05-01  2016-07-01  Down
2016-07-01  2016-11-01  Up
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and help...
It worked exactly like i wanted :)

Comment: It possibly could be optimised and made more efficient, but at least it works :)